# How can i validate in python if a username and password already exist in mySQL Database?

Tags: python-3.x, database, tkinter, mysql-python

Hi so I've been working on this project about a day now(New to python and mySQL)
So my question is how i can see if the input user credentials in the textbox is already a registered user?

So far I've managed to connect it to the database and store some values inside the database but i cant seem to figure out how i can scan that database and see if the user info are valid when the login button is pressed.

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox
import mysql.connector
import time
import datetime
import random

w = 300
h = 2

def register_user():

    global username_info
    global password_info

    if len(username.get()) == 0 and len(password.get()) == 0:
        print("Please fill in the Missing Info")

    if len(username.get()) == 0 and len(password.get()) != 0 :
            print("Please Enter a Username")
    elif len(username.get()) != 0 and len(password.get()) == 0:
                    print("Please enter a Password")


    else:
        username_info = username.get()
        password_info = password.get()

        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            passwd="root",
            database="loginsystem"
        )
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        sqlFormula = "INSERT INTO users (Username, Password) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        insertvar = (username_info, password_info)
        user1 = ("Joshua", "Cuyugan")
        mycursor.execute(sqlFormula, insertvar)
        mydb.commit()

        username.set("")
        password.set("")

def register():
    global screen1

    screen.withdraw()
    screen1 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen1.title("Registration")
    screen1.geometry("500x250+700+350")

    global username
    global password
    global username_entry
    global password_entry

    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()

    Label(screen1, text = " Please Enter Your Details Below", bg = "black", width = w , height = h, font = ("Calibri", 20) , fg = "white").pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "").pack()
    Label(screen1, text = "Username").place(x=220, y=85)
    username_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = username, width="50").place(x=100, y=110)
    Label(screen1, text = "Password").place(x=220, y=135)
    password_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = password, width="50").place(x=100, y=160)
    Button(screen1, text= "Register", height="1", width="20", command = register_user).place(x=80, y=200)
    Button(screen1, text="Cancel", height="1", width="20", command= on_closereg).place(x=270, y=200)


    screen1.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closereg)



def login():
    global screen2

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        passwd="root",
        database="loginsystem"
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    sql_select_Query = "select * from users"
    mycursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
    records = mycursor.fetchall()
    for row in records:
        print("Username" , row[1],)
        print("Password", row[2], "\n" )
        mycursor.close()

    screen.withdraw()
    screen2 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen2.title("HOT or SUPER HOT")
    screen2.geometry("800x600+550+220")


    screen2.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_close)

def checker():
    if len(username.get()) == 0 and len(password.get()) == 0:
        print("Please fill in the Missing Info")


def on_close():
    screen2.withdraw()
    screen.update()
    screen.deiconify()
    screen.lift()

def on_closereg():
    screen1.withdraw()
    screen.update()
    screen.deiconify()
    screen.lift()

def verify():
    global name
    global userlogcred
    global userpascred

    userlogcred = username_verify.get()
    userpascred = password_verify.get()

    loadname = ("SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username =%s")
    loadpass = ("SELECT Password FFROM users WHERE Password =%s")

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        passwd="root",
        database="loginsystem"
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    if len(username_verify.get()) == 0 and len(password_verify.get()) == 0:
        print("Please fill in the Missing Info")
    if len(username_verify.get()) == 0 and len(password_verify.get()) != 0 :
        print("Please Enter a Username")
    elif len(username_verify.get()) != 0 and len(password_verify.get()) == 0:
        print("Please enter a Password")

    else:
        mycursor.execute(loadname, userlogcred)
        mycursor.execute(loadpass, userpascred)
        logincheck = mycursor.fetchone()
        loginpasscheck = mycursor.fetchone()
        if logincheck is None:
            print("Sorry, could not find you in the database\nOr it just isn't working")
        if logincheck is not None and loginpasscheck is None:
            print("Please Enter your Password")
        elif logincheck is None and loginpasscheck is not None:
            print("Please enter Your Username")
        else:
            print("pass\nSuccessfully loaded {} from the database".format(username_verify.get()))



def main_Screen():

    global screen

    screen = Tk()
    screen.geometry("600x300+650+350")
    screen.title("Login System")


    Label(text = "Login System" , bg = "black", width = w , height = h, font = ("Calibri", 20) , fg = "white").pack()
    Label(text = "").pack()
    Button(text = "Login", height = h, width = "30", command = verify).place(x=50 , y=200)
    Label(text = "").pack()
    Button(text = "Register" ,height = h, width = "30", command = register).place(x=320 , y=200)


    global username_verify
    global password_verify

    username_verify = StringVar()
    password_verify = StringVar()
    Label(screen, text = "Username").place(x=265, y = 90)
    username_entry1 = Entry(screen, textvariable = username_verify, width = "80").place(x=57, y=110)
    Label(screen, text="Password").place(x=267, y=140)
    password_entry1 = Entry(screen, textvariable = password_verify, width = "80").place(x=57, y=160)

    screen.mainloop()


main_Screen()

print("Hello World")
```

Update I Found this code and I'm trying to apply it to my project where in this code compares the input value inside the textbox to the database data and it checks if the datas are already present if they are it then sends you to another form.

```
def verify():
    global name

    loadname = ("SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username =%s")
    loadpass = ("SELECT Password FFROM users WHERE Password = %s")

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        passwd="root",
        database="loginsystem"
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    if len(username_verify.get()) == 0 and len(password_verify.get()) == 0:
        print("Please fill in the Missing Info")

    if len(username_verify.get()) == 0 and len(password_verify.get()) != 0 :
            print("Please Enter a Username")
    elif len(username_verify.get()) != 0 and len(password_verify.get()) == 0:
                    print("Please enter a Password")

    else:
        mycursor.execute(loadname, username_verify.get())
        mycursor.execute(loadpass, password_verify.get())
        logincheck = mycursor.fetchone()
        loginpasscheck = mycursor.fetchone()
        if logincheck is None:
            print("Sorry, could not find you in the database\nOr it just isn't working")
        if logincheck is not None and loginpasscheck is None:
            print("Please Enter your Password")
        elif logincheck is None and loginpasscheck is not None:
            print("Please enter Your Username")
        else:
            print("pass\nSuccessfully loaded {} from the database".format(login))
```

but I encountered this erro please help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/lenovo/PycharmProjects/Pylog/App.py", line 141, in verify
    mycursor.execute(loadname, username_verify.get())
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\Pylog\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 569, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\Pylog\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 553, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\PycharmProjects\Pylog\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 442, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1
Hello World
```

Update I put the `username_verify.get()` values into variables still didn't work and it still posts the same error.

Comment: you have extra `F` in `FFROM` in `loadpass`

Comment: you use `username_verify.get()` many times in the same function so you could assign to local variable and use this variable.

Comment: in Python instead of `if len(username_verify.get()) == 0 and len(password.get()) == 0:` you can write `if username_verify.get() and password.get():`. It works like `if bool(username_verify.get()) and bool(password.get()):` and for empty string `bool()` gives `False`

Comment: value has to be in quotation marks - `'%s'`. Without quotation marks `execute()` treats value as column's name but it doesn't let you add columns to query - probably for security reason, to stop sql injection.

Comment: i did the `'%s'` but it cant detect the textbox input

Comment: do you get error ? add it in question. You can use `print()` to display values in variables. If you run function before user put text in Entry then it may not get it.

Comment: i dont get an error but even if the username and password that i put in were present in the database it couldn't detect it , it still printed the `print("Sorry, could not find you in the database\nOr it just isn't working")`

Comment: if something doesn't work then use `print()` to see values in variables - it is called "print debuging". OR learn how to use real debuger.

Comment: you run `execute()` two times and after that you use `fetchone()` two times but you will get two times values from last `execute()`

Comment: i commented the other `execute()` and left only the `mycursor.execute(loadname, userlogcred)` but it still doesnt recognize any data from the Database

Comment: as i said before - use `print()` to see values in variables - stop waisting time for guessing where is problem.

Comment: check `print( loadname, userlogcred, mycursor.fetchone() )`

Comment: i printed the 3 objects and the `mycursor.fetchone()` cant seem to find the user from the database, i already did the `'%s'`.Here is what it printed `SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username= '%s' User None`  , the variables stored in my database are Username = User and Password is = User

Comment: I don't see code which use `userlogcred` in `execute`. I see only `username_verify.get()`. Maybe it has different value. You can also create query `SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username= 'User'` and test it in any DB viewer/editor to see if it gives any result for your database. Maybe you don't have `User` in database.

Comment: Hi so i tried removing the `'%s'` and just put in the `SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username= 'User'` and i saw that the `mycursor.fetchone()` prints this ('User',) ,  dont know what to do here. and also when i ran the SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username= 'User'` in my sql it posted the data correctly. the full print is this `SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username= 'Joshua' Joshua ('Joshua',)
None
Sorry, could not find you in the database
Or it just isn't working
Hello World`

Comment: as I said before - use `print()` to check values in variables. You expect that you have `"User"` in variable which you use in `execute()` but it seems you have different text in this variable. SO use `print()` to check it. And check if you use correct variable in `execute()` - maybe you have `"User"` in variable `logincheck` but you use variable `userlogcred` in `execute()`

Comment: hi so i succesfully got it to work when i set the value of Username in `SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username= 'User'` but when i changed it back to the '%s' it doesnt detect anything here is the print `loadname is : SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username= '%s' userlogcred is User mycursor.fetchone() is : None logincheck is None
Sorry, could not find you in the database
Or it just isn't working`

Comment: do you use variable `userlogcred` in `execute()` ? In code in question I see different variable.

Comment: yes i do  `mycursor.execute(loadname, userlogcred)`

Comment: This problem has evidently been solved, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57129973/207421).

Answer (score 1):

```py
import mysql.connector as sql

class connections:
    __HOST = 'localh`o`st'
    __USERNAME = 'root'
    __PASSWORD = ''
    __DATABASE = 'testing'
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.con = sql.connect(host=connections.__HOST,user=connections.__USERNAME,password=connections.__PASSWORD,database=connections.__DATABASE)


    def connect_database(self,username,password):
        #append password and username in the emptey list below for later checkings
        mypassword_queue =[]
        sql_query = "SELECT *FROM users WHERE first_name ='%s' AND password ='%s'" % (username, password)
        mycursor = self.con.cursor()

        try:
            mycursor.execute(sql_query)
            myresults =mycursor.fetchall()
            for row in myresults:
                for x in row:
                    mypassword_queue.append(x)
        except:
            print('error occured')

        if (username and password) in mypassword_queue:
            print('there is something')
        else:
            print('there is no anything')

        self.con.close()


root = connections()
#---you must have created a database with choice of your database name for this case it is testing
#---- the data inside has name as tumusiime and password 1234
root.connect_database('tumusiime','1234')
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a code that works for me for all querys with mysql.connector

```
**config= {'user': your_user',
'password': 'your_pass',
'host': 'ip_of_your_db',
'database': 'name_of_your_db',
'raise_on_warnings': True}


def run_query(self,query):    
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(**self._config)
        if conn.is_connected():
            print('run_query: Connecting MySql Db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
        r= cur.fetchall()
        return r
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            print("run_query: Error in username or password")
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            print("run_query: Dabatase doesn't exist")
        else:
            print(err)
    finally:
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

and each Query need to have this format

```
query='SELECT * FROM {}'.format("your_db.your_table")
answer=self.run_query(query)
```