# Custom Exception for own function

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have a function in my fucntions.py that creates a MySQL database or connects to it if the database exists. It works well.

```
class InvalidLoginError():
def __init__(self, message):
   self.message = message    

# Create mysql database
def createDB(username, password, db_name):
    # URL for DB, username, password and DB name
    # User has to send db username, password and db name on function call
    url = "mysql+pymysql://" + username + ":" + password + "@localhost/" + db_name
    # url = "mysql+pymysql://root:123456@localhost/" + db_name
    # Create an engine object
    engine = create_engine(url, connect_args= dict(host='localhost', port=3306), echo=True)


    # Create database if it does not exist.
    if not database_exists(engine.url):
        create_database(engine.url)
        print("Databse " + db_name + " was successfully created")
    else:
        # Connect the database if exists.
        engine.connect()
        print("Database exists already, connection was established")
```

In my main.py I create the connection or DB with the following

```
# Variables for the connection and/or creation of the database. Please adjust as needed
username = "roiot"
db_PW = "123456"
db_name = "test_new_connect"     

# Create DB
f.createDB(username, db_PW, db_name)
```

In this example the user name is wrong. I would like to throw a custom exception like "Please check username and/ or password". I can't get it to work. I added try-except block to the function or when I call it, but it's not working as I want it to.

Where do I need to add the try-except blocks to handle the pymysql.err.OperationalError exception?

EDIT: I added the InvalidLgoinError class that I want to raise as exception.

Comment: If you want to throw a custom exception, then you have to do so with `raise <custom exception>`. `try/except` blocks are for catching exceptions, not raising them. (Though, they may be used together if you also want to catch the custom exception.)

Comment: Where is your code that raises your exception, and what problem does it exhibit?

Comment: ah, yes, this would be in the functions.py, I edited my post.

I tried to make something simple, where would I raise it then? It's my first time really working with exceptions and I am trying to get a hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

[How can i validate in python if a username and password already exist in mySQL Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57121949/how-can-i-validate-in-python-if-a-username-and-password-already-exist-in-mysql-d)
the answer here
`import mysql.connector as sql

class connections:
__HOST = 'localh`o`st'
__USERNAME = 'root'
__PASSWORD = ''
__DATABASE = 'testing'

```
def __init__(self):
    self.con = sql.connect(host=connections.__HOST,user=connections.__USERNAME,password=connections.__PASSWORD,database=connections.__DATABASE)


def connect_database(self,username,password):
    #append password and username in the emptey list below for later checkings
    mypassword_queue =[]
    sql_query = "SELECT *FROM users WHERE first_name ='%s' AND password ='%s'" % (username, password)
    mycursor = self.con.cursor()

    try:
        mycursor.execute(sql_query)
        myresults =mycursor.fetchall()
        for row in myresults:
            for x in row:
                mypassword_queue.append(x)
    except:
        print('error occured')

    if (username and password) in mypassword_queue:
        print('there is something')
    else:
        print('there is no anything')

    self.con.close()
```

root = connections()
#---you must have created a database with choice of your database name for this case it is testing
#---- the data inside has name as tumusiime and password 1234
root.connect_database('tumusiime','1234')`
this seems like it would solve your problem.